# Countdown timer in second activity stops when the value of the time is sent to first activity

Tags: android, android-intent, timer

I have a timer in my SecondActivity that sends the value to my first activity, and then starts counting down, but when I go back to my SecondActivity the timer has totally stopped and gone back to 00:00. I'm not quite sure what is going on. Does anyone know what is happening. Im thinking maybe the problem is that when I click the button to go to the second activity it is creating a whole new instance of it. If so does anyone have some idea of how I could fix this.

Heres the code...

```
buttonStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //put your logic here to set the time with hourPicked and minPicked variables
        timer = new CounterClass((hours * 60 * 1000) + (minutes * 1000), 1000);
        String hms = String.format(("%02d:%02d"), hours, minutes);
        textViewTime.setText(hms);
        Intent intent = new Intent(SleepTimer.this, MainActivity.class);
        String TimeValue = (hms);
        intent.putExtra("TimeValue", TimeValue);
        startActivity(intent);
        timer.start();
    }
});
```

Comment: what is your launch mode in menifest

Comment: Im not sure how do I check that

Comment: post code for sending time to first Activity

Comment: open your manifest file .....in your activity tag give single task for launch mode for second activity  because of this system uses the same instance property which is created earlier   <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask
             </activity>

Comment: This doesn't change anything

Comment: I figured it out. I needed to set the launchmode to singleInstance